# Table Audit Trigger with Stored Procedure ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-trigger, audit-trail

I have process that is kicked off by a stored procedure which goes several layers deep.  Up to 12 subsequent stored procedures could be involved.

I have a table that is getting a column updated incorrectly during the above process and I would like to find out which stored procedure is the one making the erroneous update.

I have looked at table auditing via triggers and have tried using the SCOPE_IDENTITY function to identify which stored procedure is the culprit but it returns a NULL value to my audit table.

Is what I am trying to do possible? I'm basically trying to use this instead of debugging which I have had limited success with in the past, and I would rather not like to edit the stored procedures in order to capture the information.

Here is my code: I have created a test stored procedure to update the table in question.

```
    --Create test Sproc

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects (NOLOCK) WHERE name LIKE 'usp_update_pkd')
    BEGIN 
      DROP PROCEDURE usp_update_pkd
    END
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_update_pkd
    @p_order_number VARCHAR(30)

    AS

    UPDATE t_pick_detail
    SET status =  'XXX'
    WHERE order_number = @p_order_number
    RETURN
    GO


    --Create Audit Table
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects (NOLOCK) WHERE name LIKE 't_pkd_audit')
      BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE t_pkd_audit
      END
    GO
    CREATE TABLE t_pkd_audit
    (
      order_audit_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      wave_id        VARCHAR(10),
      work_type      VARCHAR(20),
      order_number   VARCHAR(20),
      sproc_id       NVARCHAR(128),
      updated_on     DATETIME
    )
    GO

      --Create Trigger
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects (NOLOCK) WHERE name LIKE 'pkd_audit_record') 
    BEGIN 
      DROP TRIGGER pkd_audit_record
    END
    GO

    CREATE TRIGGER pkd_audit_record ON t_pick_detail
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO t_pkd_audit 
      (wave_id, work_type, order_number, sproc_id, updated_on )
      SELECT DISTINCT i.wave_id, i.work_type, i.order_number, CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR), GETDATE() 
      FROM  t_pick_detail t 
      INNER JOIN inserted i
      ON  t.order_number = i.order_number
      AND t.line_number  = i.line_number 
    END
    GO

    --Execute test SProc
    EXEC usp_update_pkd '4045'

    --Check Results
    SELECT * FROM t_pkd_audit (NOLOCK)

--Result Set
order_audit_id|wave_id|work_type|order_number|sproc_id|updated_on
1             |NULL   |17       |4045        |NULL    |2017-06-22 00:47:52.513
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried context_info? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql

Comment: Hi Peter, from what I read, that would require me to modify the stored procedures in question and set the context_info value within their source code.  Is my understanding correct?  If there is no other way that SQL server implicitly tracks which procedure it is in when performing DML, then that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your audit table that will contain the stored procedure name. Because it has a default value, you don't need to alter you trigger, but you can remove sproc_id if you like. The default value will take the @@PROCID stored in context_info and use it to get the Stored Procedure name.

```
CREATE TABLE t_pkd_audit
(
    order_audit_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    wave_id        VARCHAR(10),
    work_type      VARCHAR(20),
    order_number   VARCHAR(20),
    sproc_id       NVARCHAR(128),
    updated_on     DATETIME,
    SpName [varchar](128) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_a_hist_sourceName]  DEFAULT (object_name(CONVERT([int],CONVERT([varbinary](4),context_info()))))
)
```

For each of your 12 stored procedures, start with:

```
declare @calledBy varbinary(128) = coalesce(Context_info(),0),@proc int
select @proc = @@PROCID
set context_info @proc
```

It will put the id of the stored procedure in context_info and store the id of the parent stored procedure in a variable.

At the end of each stored procedure. If you use returns, than also before each return add the folowing code to write back the id of the parent stored procedure back in context_info.

```
set context_info @calledby
```

Comment: Thanks Peter,  after reading your 1st comment I went away and tried some things and essentially arrived at your submitted answer.  Thanks again for your help.  I triggered the process from the application and low and behold had the offending sproc name in the audit table when it had finished!  Bug found and fixed!